# ¿como hago un backup de mi base de datos desde mi web con php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

hola soy nuevo en esto de la programación y quisiera queme ayudaran  hacer un respaldo de mi base de datos desde un botón de mi pagina web. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido freddy, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] así puedes mejorar tu pregunta y recibir buenas respuestas, así como está es demasiado amplia y susceptible a las opiniones, cosas que son causales de cierre. Saludos

Comment: Es una muy mala idea hacer eso, más aún si tu web es pública. Imagina que todo el que entre le de a ese botón. Tú puedes crear un script que corra en el servidor y programar un Cron para hacer el backup, poniendo los intervalos de tiempo que quieras. Y puedes hasta enviarte al email la copia que se hizo y/o guardarla en una carpeta o en la nube... todo en background, más rápido, más seguro, más transparente.

Comment: es para un proyecto de mi universidad nada mas, además la parte del respaldo solo lo podrá hacer el administrador de la base de datos(creare 3 usuarios para la prueba), gracias por tu consejo , lo tendré muy en cuenta...

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow sirve para ayudarte a evacuar dudas concretas, en tu caso estás preguntando como realizar un sistema completo.

Lo que puedo responder a tu pregunta es que debes de realizar un select de toda la base y luego convertirlo en un CSV (archivo de excel) o tal vez hay alguna herramienta que te exporte en sql desde la base de datos, algo así https://github.com/2createStudio/shuttle-export

Saludos